# Bash script which starts Firefox and then close it

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script that:

1. Delete all Firefox cookies
2. Start Firefox - open a url, for example www.google.com
3. Load the page
4. Quit Firefox
5. Output all cookies to a text file

I want to run the script via PHP or SSH, but I don't get it to work. Firefox doesn't start. Do you know what's wrong?

```
sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/4cgsngb1.cookie1/cookies.sqlite 'delete from moz_cookies'
export DISPLAY=:0
firefox http://www.google.com &
PID=`jobs -p`
kill $PID
sqlite3 .mozilla/firefox/4cgsngb1.cookie1/cookies.sqlite 'select * from moz_cookies'
```

Comment: looks like curl is much more suitable for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a graphical application headless unless you install a virtual framebuffer (e.g. `Xvfb`) to the remote machine or, in case of SSH, unless you forward the graphical output to the local machine (with `ssh -X`).

Comment: Thanks! For example: xvfb-run firefox http://www.google.com or is it more complicated?

Comment: You should probably be looking at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to run Firefox properly isolated from your regular browser, have it shut down in a controlled manner, etc.